# How can I delete and recreate a CDK Stack (Cloudformation) using a lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-cdk

I have a stack in cloudformation (created using AWS CDK) that creates an EC2 instance. Every 30 days I want to recreate that instance, i.e. delete and recreate the stack.

Is it possible to do it using a lambda with eventbridge rules, maybe?

How could I deploy/create the stack from a cfn template stored in S3. Using boto3.

Comment: I believe lambda has a runtime limit of 15-minudes. That may impede your ability to do a 'cdk deploy'.  Must it be lambda? There are many other ways to schedule the execution of code that don't have the same limitations.

Comment: Do you want a lambda function to create or delete a stack? Is that what you intended to do?

Comment: @SteveJ You are right. I was also thinking of deploying/creating the stack using a cfn template stored in S3. Using boto3. That could work. What do you think?

Comment: @FrancisZabala delete the stack and recreate it from a cfn template stored in s3, using boto3.

Comment: One approach is to use your CI/CD tool. Most of the popular ones, BB, Jenkins, GH, AWS -- have a way to run pipelines on a schedule. That way, you can leave your CF in your repo and run it from there, without a push to S3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the [SDKs AWS provides](https://aws.amazon.com/developer/tools/) to create a lambda that does what you want.  For example, you could write a lambda using Python code and the [Python SDK](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html) to invoke API functions such as [delete_stack](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.delete_stack) or [create_stack](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.create_stack) to do what you want.

There are many good tutorials available that cover how to create a lambda that uses one of the SDKs lambda supports.  You can use [EventBridge to schedule the lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-run-lambda-schedule.html) to run every 30 days.  If you have the CloudFormation template available, say, in S3, then the lambda can easily consume it and use it for creating a stack.  You won't necessarily be using the CDK inside the lambda, but you accomplish pretty much the same thing using an SDK.

Or if you really want to use the CDK inside lambda, you could do something [like this](https://dev.to/mraszplewicz/running-aws-cdk-from-a-lambda-function-3502).  Also, [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/scheduling-automatic-deletion-of-aws-cloudformation-stacks/) gives a nice walk-through of many of the steps to do something very similar using the Python SDK.